# Rangos en for python 3.9.2

Tags: python, bucle-for, bucles

Estoy iniciando en python y encontré un ejemplo de uso de **rangos** en ciclos **for** el problema es que al tratar de imprimir el ciclo me marca un error en el print, estuve buscando información y lamentablemte no encontre nada.

```
for i in range(5, 0, -1):
print(i) #5,4,3,2,1
```

Donde marca el error es en *print*

Comment: ¿Qué error te marca?

Comment: Tu problema tiene que ver con la indentación, tienes que poner el espaciado o la sangría, como gustes llamarlo, hacia la derecha para indicar al programa que la línea de código `print(i)` corresponde al ciclo `for`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for i in range(5,0,-1):
    #Tienes que añadir una indentación a la derecha
    print(i) #5,4,3,2,1
```

Comment: soy principiante tambien en python , en el print tenes que dejar una identacion (un espacio) debajo del bucle for,  para que pueda ejecutarlo.

Comment: Nop, no es necesario la indentación si solo pones una instrucción. Todo iría en una sola línea

Comment: Tienes razón, tengo que repasar más. Muchas gracias por tu comentario : )

Comment: No te preocupes estamos aquí para ayudar. Gracias por contribuir a la comunidad :D